# Eliminate the parameter and sketch the curve

Tags: calculus

The question is (in parametric equations):

$$x = 2\sin(t)$$
$$y = \cos(t)$$

for $0 \le t \le \pi/2$

I need to eliminate the parameter and the sketch the curve... any ideas?

Comment: Do you know an ellipse?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The parametric equation (almost) looks like that of a circle and in particular we have
$$\frac{x^2}{2^2} + y^2 = 1$$
Do you know what kind of curve this describes? How much of the curve is traversed? In what direction?

For further reference, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equations).

Comment: It looks like an ellipse or circle?

Comment: Technically it **is** an ellipse. Are you familiar with the Cartesian expression for the ellipse? I've added a link that should help a bit.

Comment: Um is it 1/x^2 + 1/y^2 = r?

Comment: No! That would give you a degree four curve, namely $x^2 + y^2 - rx^2y^2 = 0.$ An ellipse is a conic section, so has a degree two equation: $ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$. All of the $a$, $b$, $c$, $f$, $g$ and $h$ are fixed numbers of your choice. If $h^2 - ab < 0$ then you have an ellipse, if $h^2-ab = 0$ then you have a parabola. If $h^2 - ab > 0$ then you have a hyperbola.